# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'childNodes')

Tags: javascript, xml, domparser, child-nodes

I am trying to parse a text to a text/xml and get the value that is inside a child Node but is giving this error to me (Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'childNodes').
I want the value true inside of the GetValidUserPasswordResult.
This is the code that i am making:

```
    var text = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><GetValidUserPasswordResponse xmlns="http://microsoft.com/webservices/"><GetValidUserPasswordResult>true</GetValidUserPasswordResult></GetValidUserPasswordResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>';
    console.log(text);
    parser = new DomParser();
    xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text, "text/xml");


xmlDoc1 = xmlDoc.getElementsByName("GetValidUserPasswordResult")[0].childNodes[0].text;
console.log(xmlDoc1)
```

Comment: You use `xmlDoc.getElementsByName`, but there is no element with the `name` attribute value "GetValidUserPasswordResult". You probably meant `xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName`. Also to get the text from an element use `.textContent` instead of `.text`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found the answer, i was doing on node.js but the implementation of DOMParser on node is xmldom, so the result was this one

```js
var DOMParser = require('xmldom').DOMParser;
var parser = new DOMParser();
var document = parser.parseFromString('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><GetValidUserPasswordResponse xmlns="http://microsoft.com/webservices/"><GetValidUserPasswordResult>true</GetValidUserPasswordResult></GetValidUserPasswordResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>', 'text/xml');
var xmlDoc1 = document.getElementsByTagName("GetValidUserPasswordResult")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
console.log(xmlDoc1)
```